# Аналог функции nearZeroVar (язык R) в Python

Tags: python, r

Есть ли в Python функция, которая бы работала аналогично функции nearZeroVar в языке R?

Comment: Расскажите, что делает эта функция?

Comment: Ну прям аналога вроде нет, но вы можете сами в `Pandas` что нужно посчитать, там вроде ничего сложного не вычисляется такого уж прям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите пакет pycaret.

```
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
juice = get_data('juice')
from pycaret.classification import *
exp_name = setup(data = juice,  target = 'Purchase', ignore_low_variance = True)
```